# jQuery :contains("\u00a0") does not work with IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net-2.0

I have a DataList populated from XML and some cells contain only `&nbsp ;` (the space there was to get it to show in this post).

I am using jQuery to remove those rows with

```
$('td:contains("\u00a0")').closest('tr').hide();
```

This works great in everything but IE. It comes down to the \u00a0 that is failing. I can't use " " as other cells will have some spaces in them, and `&nbsp ;` doesn't do anything either.

Any help on how to remove the row if a cell in it contains `&nbsp ;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the following solution?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $.each($('td'), function (e, i) { if ($.trim($(i).text()).length == 0) { $(i).closest('tr').remove(); } });
});
```

Comment: I would like to throw out a "Hell Yay" for that. It worked great. Thanks much